# Convert a correlation matrix to a covariance matrix in R?

Tags: r, correlation, covariance

Suppose I have a correlation matrix

```
A <- matrix(c(1,0.3,-0.5,0.3,1,0.5,-0.5,0.5,1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.3 -0.5
[2,]  0.3  1.0  0.5
[3,] -0.5  0.5  1.0
```

is it possible to convert this to a variance covariance matrix in rstudio?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with R Studio. It's an R question.

Comment: It is rather a math question no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If A is an n x n correlation matrix then the covariance matrix is

```
diag(s) %*% A %*% diag(s)
```

where s is the n-vector of standard deviations.